# aviso: ‘struct qelem’ declarado dentro de la list de parámetros no será visible fuera de esta definición o declaración

Tags: c, compilar, gcc

Estoy tratando de compilar [*gzilla 0.3.4*](https://www.levien.com/gzilla/), y me sale un error en el archivo `LDH.h`.

```
/*
   Doubly Linked lists
   1998, Randall Maas

   This uses the standard C qelem struct and insque/remque to perform its
   operations.  It adds a function called appque which will append the element
   to the very end of the list.
*/

#ifndef __LDL_h
# define __LDL_h

// ...
// ...
// ...

# ifndef def_LDL_cat
extern inline
# endif
void _LDL_cat(struct qelem* LMain, struct qelem* LSub, struct qelem* LTail)
{
   /* This appends the sub list onto the end of the main list */
   /* Have the main list continue onto the new list */
   LMain->q_back->q_forw = LSub;
   
   /* Have the new list refer back to the old list */
   LSub->q_back = LMain->q_back;
   
   /* Have the tail pointer for the main list updated */
   LMain->q_back = LTail;
   
   /* Have the tail pointer continue back to the head */
   LTail->q_forw = LMain;
}
```

Primer error:

```
LDL.h:81:22: aviso: ‘struct qelem’ declarado dentro de la list de parámetros no será visible fuera de esta definición o declaración
   81 | void _LDL_cat(struct qelem* LMain, struct qelem* LSub, struct qelem* LTail)
      |                      ^~~~~
```

Todos los errores de ese archivo:

```
LDL.h:81:22: aviso: ‘struct qelem’ declarado dentro de la list de parámetros no será visible fuera de esta definición o declaración
   81 | void _LDL_cat(struct qelem* LMain, struct qelem* LSub, struct qelem* LTail)
      |                      ^~~~~
LDL.h: En la función ‘_LDL_cat’:
LDL.h:85:9: error: uso no válido del tipo indefinido ‘struct qelem’
   85 |    LMain->q_back->q_forw = LSub;
      |         ^~
LDL.h:88:8: error: uso no válido del tipo indefinido ‘struct qelem’
   88 |    LSub->q_back = LMain->q_back;
      |        ^~
LDL.h:88:24: error: uso no válido del tipo indefinido ‘struct qelem’
   88 |    LSub->q_back = LMain->q_back;
      |                        ^~
LDL.h:91:9: error: uso no válido del tipo indefinido ‘struct qelem’
   91 |    LMain->q_back = LTail;
      |         ^~
LDL.h:94:9: error: uso no válido del tipo indefinido ‘struct qelem’
   94 |    LTail->q_forw = LMain;
      |         ^~
LDL.h: En el nivel principal:
LDL.h:111:26: aviso: ‘struct qelem’ declarado dentro de la list de parámetros no será visible fuera de esta definición o declaración
  111 | size_t LDL_length(struct qelem* L)
      |                          ^~~~~
LDL.h: En la función ‘LDL_length’:
LDL.h:57:23: error: uso no válido del tipo indefinido ‘struct qelem’
   57 |         for(IPtr=(LDL)->q_forw; IPtr && IPtr != (LDL); IPtr = IPtr->q_forw)
      |                       ^~
LDL.h:115:4: nota: en expansión de macro ‘LDL_foreach’
  115 |    LDL_foreach(IPtr, L) I++;
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~
LDL.h:57:67: error: uso no válido del tipo indefinido ‘struct qelem’
   57 |         for(IPtr=(LDL)->q_forw; IPtr && IPtr != (LDL); IPtr = IPtr->q_forw)
      |                                                                   ^~
LDL.h:115:4: nota: en expansión de macro ‘LDL_foreach’
  115 |    LDL_foreach(IPtr, L) I++;
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es declarar el `struct` que viene en el archivo `/usr/include/search.h` del paquete *libc6-dev*.

```
# ifndef def_LDL_cat
struct qelem
{
    struct qelem *q_forw;
    struct qelem *q_back;
    char q_data[1];
};
```

Quedando en el código de la siguiente manera:

```
# ifndef def_LDL_cat
struct qelem
{
    struct qelem *q_forw;
    struct qelem *q_back;
    char q_data[1];
};
extern inline
# endif
void _LDL_cat(struct qelem* LMain, struct qelem* LSub, struct qelem* LTail)
{
   /* This appends the sub list onto the end of the main list */
   /* Have the main list continue onto the new list */
   LMain->q_back->q_forw = LSub;
   
   /* Have the new list refer back to the old list */
   LSub->q_back = LMain->q_back;
   
   /* Have the tail pointer for the main list updated */
   LMain->q_back = LTail;
   
   /* Have the tail pointer continue back to the head */
   LTail->q_forw = LMain;
}
```